# ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression for 700k rows

Tags: postgresql

I've two table 'trip_history' and 'dap_iot_stdd_details'.

`trip_history` table has `trip_id` column whereas `dap_iot_stdd_details` table has `trip_id, dap_iot_stdd_id, added_on, "timestamp"`.

All i want is to extract data from dap_iot_stdd_details using trip_id from trip_history table.

I tried to execute this

```
select dap_iot_stdd_id, added_on, "timestamp"
from public.dap_iot_stdd_details
where dap_iot_trip_id = (
  select trip_id
  from public.trip_history
  where start_time between '1680307200000' and '1680912000000'
  order by start_time asc
);
```

and i'm getting
`Error "more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression"`
as expected.

I would like to know if there is a better way to recreate this query.

Please note that there are over 700k trip id's for which respective data is required from dap_iot_stdd_details.
I'm quite a beginner in Postgresql. Let me know if i'm doing anything wrong here.

Comment: It's not clear what exactly the desired result is. Do you want to use `IN` instead of `=`? Are you trying to `JOIN` the tables? Did you mean to add `LIMIT 1` to get only the first row in that start time interval?

Comment: I'm guessing that `...dap_iot_stdd_details table has trip_id, ...` is meant to be `dap_iot_stdd_details table has dap_iot_trip_id,...` per what is shown in the query itself. FYI, using an integer string for timestamp values is not a good idea, you probably store in a `timestamptz` field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the error because of this:

```
where dap_iot_trip_id = (
  select trip_id ...
```

The subquery(`select trip_id ..`) in this context can only return one value to be valid.

As @Bergi mentioned you could change that per [Subquery expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html) to:

```
where dap_iot_trip_id IN (
  select trip_id ...
```

Read the docs at the link for the caveats.

Or you could turn the query into a `JOIN` form as also suggested:

```
SELECT 
    dap_iot_stdd_id, added_on, "timestamp"
FROM 
    public.dap_iot_stdd_details AS detail 
JOIN
    public.trip_history AS history
ON
    detail.dap_iot_trip_id = history.trip_id
WHERE 
    history.start_time BETWEEN '1680307200000' AND '1680912000000'
ORDER BY 
    start_time asc
```